# How do you import type definitions from `@types` typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 2.0 with the lastest `ionic@RC.0` build process.

I installed the google-maps types like this:

`npm install @types/google-maps --save-dev --save-exact`

and I'm trying to import some of the type definitions into my code like this

```
/// <reference types="google-maps" />
import { LatLng, LatLngBounds } from 'google-maps';
```

but I get this typescript error:

`./node_modules/@types/google-maps/index.d.ts has no exported member 'LatLng'`

and if I look in the source, I actually find the definition in

`./node_modules/@types/google-maps/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts`

Answer (score 17):

Add a reference to the types package in the file `tsconfig.json` in the root folder of your project:

```
"types": [
    "google-maps"
]
```

Don't import anything in your source files, the types are globally defined.

Comment: The problem is that you will have to specificy ALL types like this if you start adding some manually, as far as I understand TypeScript won't load them automatically. This feature is firest meant as whitelist, not a global import system.

Comment: Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types says `import type { APIResponseType } from "./api";`

Answer (score 2):

The `import` only works for the current package, not its dependencies.

So you need to `import { LatLng, LatLngBounds } from 'googlemaps'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18095085)

Comment: Actually, my answer is the same as @Sam. Please take carefully it's `googlemaps`!

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the wrong declaration file. The one you are using is:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-maps/index.d.ts which does not expose LatLng.

The declaration file you linked to is: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts

`googlemaps` vs `google-maps`