# Problems with @types library in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to install typescript library for example `howler`. I use this command:

```
yarn add @types/howler
```

It has been installed successfully. But when I import it with `import { Howl } from 'howler'` and execute application by `vue-cli-service serve`, it throws error:
[image]

If i install just `howler` without `@types` it works fine with  `declare module ...`.
What's the problem, help please.

Comment: Types aren't usually directly imported like that. You likely need to add it to your tsconfig

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818429/how-do-you-import-type-definitions-from-types-typescript-2-0)

Comment: I added `howler` to dependencies and `@types/howler` to devDependencies. It works fine. So, why I shouldn't use `add` like this? many popular libraries say to install them with `@types/....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install both `howler` *and* `@types/howler`.

- `howler` is the actual code. Without it there is nothing to execute. This typically goes in `dependencies`
- `@types/howler` is the types for that code. There is no executable code in this package, just information about how the code in the `howler` package works. This always goes in `devDependencies` since the types are not required in production.

You never use `@types/package-name-here` alone without the corresponding package installed as well.

Comment: Yeap, thanks, I already came to this by myself, but yours answer is full and usefull